# WordPress AJAX load post metadata in modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, metabox, post-meta

I have a custom page template (front-page.php) and I have a custom metabox which is assigned to this page template.

Metabox have 7 sections, and each section have 2 inputs. It looks like:
1. Client logo image url (input)
2. Client details (textarea)

At frontend showing 7 client logos via:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'client_logo', true); ?>
```

What I need to do is to AJAX load client details post meta in the modal box when you click on the clients logo.

If you click on client 1 logo you see client 1 details, if on client 2 logo you see details post meta for client 2, etc etc

I have some code but I have no idea how to use it. Maybe someone have a solution for this?

```
( function( $ ) {
// AJAX loading client information
    var page = 1;
    var loading = true;
    var load_posts = function(){
            $.ajax({
                type       : "GET",
                data       : {'What should be here?'},
                dataType   : "html",
                url        : "link to php file which is return data? what should be at the php file?",
                success    : function(data){
                    } else {
                    }
                },
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }
        });
    }

    // Load more posts on click
    $('a.popup').click(function() {
      loading = true;
      load_posts();
      return false;
    });
    load_posts();
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: you can use the helpers of WordPress to use AJAX : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: If you only have 7 items, then AJAX is overkill for this application. You could use thickbox and add the post_meta to hidden divs when the page loads. See the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox#Example

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. 
Yeah I know re:thickbox, problem is that my client says to use ajax...

Comment: This post looks useful but its about post loading in modal with ajax, plus looks like it have some bugs in code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631347/ajax-wordpress-post-popup-with-simplemodal-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax url creating methode of wordpress.

```
add_action("wp_ajax_clientLogoPopup", "clientLogoPopup");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_clientLogoPopup", "clientLogoPopup");

    function clientLogoPopup()
    {
        $clientID = intval($_REQUEST['client_id']);
        if($clientID > 0){
            echo get_post_meta($clientID , 'client_logo', true);
            // or you can also show other meta fields here.
        }
        die();
    }
```

write above script in functions.php of your theme

now call the url as per your requirement like this,

http://www.your-website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=clientLogoPopup&client_id=